# WASAPI capture data is only 00 and FF

Tags: c++, audio, wasapi

If I open the captured PCM data with a Hex eitor they are only combinations of 00 and FF bytes.It seems to capture only static noise on my laptop and pc.On my pc, the recording device (Stereo Mix - Realtek High Definiton Audio) and on my laptop I use the recording device Stereo Mix (Realtek Audio) .I can modify the WAVEFORMATEX and change the driver format but I still only get different kind of loud static noises or no sound at all...If I use Audacity to capture, it works, so the problem must be at my code...

```
     HRESULT InitAudio() {
HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
REFERENCE_TIME hnsRequestedDuration;
REFERENCE_TIME hnsActualDuration;
UINT32 bufferFrameCount;
IMMDeviceEnumerator *pEnumerator = NULL;
IMMDeviceCollection* pIMMDeviceCollection = NULL;
IMMDevice *pDevice = NULL;
_AudioSamplesReadyEvent = CreateEventEx(NULL, NULL, 0, EVENT_MODIFY_STATE | SYNCHRONIZE);
_ShutdownEvent = CreateEventEx(NULL, NULL, 0, EVENT_MODIFY_STATE | SYNCHRONIZE);

    WAVEFORMATEX                wfx =
  {WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, wavFile.num_channels, wavFile.sample_rate, wavFile.byte_rate, wavFile.sample_alignment, wavFile.bit_depth, 0};

hr = CoCreateInstance(
       CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL,
       CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
       (void**)&pEnumerator);

hr = pEnumerator->EnumAudioEndpoints(eCapture,DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE,&pIMMDeviceCollection);
hr = pIMMDeviceCollection->Item(0, &pDevice);

hr = pDevice->Activate(
                IID_IAudioClient, CLSCTX_ALL,
                NULL, (void**)&pAudioClient);

hr = pAudioClient->GetDevicePeriod(NULL, &hnsRequestedDuration);
hr = pAudioClient->Initialize(
                     AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED,
                     AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_EVENTCALLBACK | AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_NOPERSIST,
                     hnsRequestedDuration,
                     0,
                     &wfx,
                     NULL);


hr = pAudioClient->SetEventHandle(_AudioSamplesReadyEvent);
if (FAILED(hr)) MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Unable to set event handle!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

hr = pAudioClient->GetService(
                     IID_IAudioCaptureClient,
                     (void**)&pCaptureClient);

ProcessSoundThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ProcessSound, 0, 0, NULL);

hr = pAudioClient->Start();  // Start recording.

return hr;
}
```

and the function that is used to process the data

```
    DWORD WINAPI ProcessSound(void* arg) {
UINT32 numFramesAvailable;
UINT32 packetLength = 0;
UINT32 dataSize = 0;
BYTE *pData;
DWORD  flags;
HRESULT hr;
UINT dwDataWrote;

HANDLE waitArray[2] = { _AudioSamplesReadyEvent, _ShutdownEvent};
HANDLE mmcssHandle = NULL;
DWORD mmcssTaskIndex = 0;

hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
if (FAILED(hr)) MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Unable to initialize COM in render thread!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

mmcssHandle = AvSetMmThreadCharacteristics("Audio", &mmcssTaskIndex);
if(mmcssHandle == NULL) MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Unable to enable MMCSS on capture thread!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

while(captureSound) {
    DWORD waitResult = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, waitArray, FALSE, INFINITE);
    switch (waitResult)
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0:
            hr = pCaptureClient->GetBuffer(&pData,&numFramesAvailable,&flags,NULL,NULL);
            if(hr != AUDCLNT_S_BUFFER_EMPTY) {
                dataSize = numFramesAvailable * wavFile.sample_alignment; // wavFile.sample_alignment = frameSize = num_channels * (pWav->bit_depth)/8
                if (FAILED( addWavData(&wavFile, pData, dataSize, &dwDataWrote)))
                    MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Error writting the data!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 
                totalData += dataSize;
            }
            pCaptureClient->ReleaseBuffer(numFramesAvailable);
            break;
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:   
            captureSound = false;
            break;
        }`
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you listening to the correct input?  You code assumes that it is the first device, but you can have more than one.

Comment: Hi, I'll try to listen to all devices and see if its different then come back.Thanks.

Comment: It seems that only device 0 works, pIMMDeviceCollection->Item(0, &pDevice); or hr = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eCapture, eConsole, &pDevice); its still only 00 and FF basically noise...